# Regular expression parsed with grepl replacement

Tags: regex, r, gsub, grepl

The objective is to parse a regular expression and replace the matched pattern.

Consider this example:

```
data <- c("cat 6kg","cat g250", "cat dog","cat 10 kg")
```

I have to locate all occurrences of `cat` and a number `[0-9]`. To do this:

```
found <- data[grepl("(^cat.[a-z][0-9])|(^cat.[0-9])",data)]
found
[1] "cat 6kg"   "cat g250"  "cat 10 kg"
```

The next step is to replace each element of `found` with string `cat`. I have attempted **gsub**, **sub**, and **gsubfn()** from package (gsubfn) according to Stack question 20219311:

```
gsubfn("((^cat.[a-z][0-9])|(^cat.[0-9]))", "cat",data)
[1] "catkg"   "cat50"   "cat dog" "cat0 kg"
```

which is NOT the expected result:

```
[#] "cat" "cat" "cat dog" "cat"
```

I think I'm missing a point. I would appreciate any help I could get. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple,,,, Just assign the string `cat` to the match elements. This will replace all the chars present in the element with `cat`

```
> data <- c("cat 6kg","cat g250", "cat dog","cat 10 kg") 
> data[grepl("(^cat.[a-z][0-9])|(^cat.[0-9])",data)] <- "cat"
> data
[1] "cat"     "cat"     "cat dog" "cat"
```

or

```
> data <- c("cat 6kg","cat g250", "cat dog","cat 10 kg") 
> data[grepl("^cat.[a-z]?[0-9]",data)] <- "cat"
> data
[1] "cat"     "cat"     "cat dog" "cat"
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash. Just curious why didn't gsub work? Also, how to automate the replacement for any string `str` (ie, `cat`). Do I have to use paste()...

Comment: @remi gsubfn just replaces all the matched chars with `cat`, so it leaves the unmatched characters. try `gsub("^cat.[a-z]?[0-9].*", "cat", x)` . This would match all the remaining chars because we added `.*` at the last.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
 sub('\\s*dog(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=cat).*', '', data, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "cat"     "cat"     "cat dog" "cat"
```

Or

```
 sub('(cat)\\s*([0-9]|[a-z][0-9]).*$', '\\1', data)
 #[1] "cat"     "cat"     "cat dog" "cat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gsub('(\\w?[0-9].*)','',data)
#[1] "cat "    "cat "    "cat dog" "cat "
```