# Replace only parsed regular expression

Tags: regex, r, gsub, grepl

This question is similar to Stack question [Regular expression parsed with grepl replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625706/regular-expression-parsed-with-grepl-replacement).

The objective is to parse a regular expression and replace ONLY the matched pattern. The example:

```
data <- c("cat 6kg","cat g250", "dog","cat 10 kg", "no cat")
```

To parse matches of interest `cat`:

```
data[grepl("cat",data)]
[1] "cat 6kg"   "cat g250"  "cat 10 kg" "no cat"
```

The ideal result replaces all the occurrences of `cat` with `chicken`:

```
[1] "chicken 6kg"   "chicken g250"  "chicken 10 kg" "no chicken"
```

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gsub:

```
gsub("cat", "chicken", data)

[1] "chicken 6kg"   "chicken g250"  "dog"           "chicken 10 kg" "no chicken"
```

or if you only want ones containing cat:

```
gsub("cat", "chicken", data[grepl("cat",data)])

[1] "chicken 6kg"   "chicken g250"  "chicken 10 kg" "no chicken"
```

Comment: Thanks! It does the trick. I forgot to mention that the result should keep the "dog" entry as well (unaltered). Any idea how to do that?